# c true statement for loop keeps coming true in hangman

Tags: c, arrays, loops, while-loop

kk i fixed it but there is still one statement i have to put i think which is `if (hit == length)` then outside the `while` loop `printf` you won. but my question now where should i put the `if (hit == length)`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <string.h>

//function prototypes

void game(char [], char [], int);
int main()
{
    char word[20] = {'d', 'u','c','k'};
    char guessed[20] ={'*s', '*s','*s','*s' };
    int length = strlen(word);

    game(word,guessed, length);

    getch();
    return 0;   
} 
void game(char answer[], char guess[], int length)
{
    int life = 5;   
    int x = 0;
    int y = 0;
    char letter;

    while (x < length && life > 0){
      int hit = 0;
      printf("enter letter\n");
      scanf(" %c",&letter);   
      for (y = 0; y < length; ++y) {
          if (answer[y] == letter && guess[y] != letter) 
          {
              ++hit;
              guess[y] = letter;
          }
      }
      if (!hit) 
      {
          x += hit; 
          printf("try again\n");
          life = life - 1;
          printf("%d tries remaining \n", life); 
      }
      else {
          printf("keep going\n");
      }  
   } 
}
```

Comment: Best situation ever to use a debugger.

Comment: Also, formatting code correcly never hurts.

Comment: What is `'*s'` supposed to do?

Comment: one problem with questions about word games - their authors never explain the workflow of the game, but immediately start discussing the error

Answer (score 0):

Your condition `if (!hit)` checks out if `hit` is 0 or not.

However, you initialize it to 0 only once, at the beginning of the procedure - and not for every iteration of your `while(..)` loop.

Therefore - once `hit` was set to be not 0 (in some iteration) it will always remain that way (not 0).

You should set `hit = 0;` inside the `while` loop (probably at its start).

Answer (score 0):

You should set hit to 0 at the start of your while loop so it'll check hit seperately for every iteration of the for loop :P

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
char guessed[20] ={ '*', '*','*','*' };
....
if (!hit) {
    printf("try again\n");
    life = life - 1;
    printf("%d tries remaining \n", life); 
}
else {
    x = hit; 
    printf("keep going\n");
}
```